# jquery google chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I am using the newest jqueryui and have a link on my homepage that bring a dialog with a form. Now on Firefox, IE and the others no problems. Only on chrome. it just won't work. You click and it's just quiet.
Here is the simple code that gets the dialog:

```
var diagopt = {
    autoOpen: true,
            title: 'Get a Quote Sent to you!',
    modal: true,
    width: 400,
    height: 350 } d.each(function(){ //d is a variable holding jquery object
$(this).click(function(eve){
    if($(this).attr('id') == links[1]) //array with id of target elements
        {
            $('#getquote').dialog(diagopt);
            return false;
        }
```

Is there anything I am missing or is it one of those css quirks that chrome just doesn't like coming from jqueryui which I see spoken of by some other users here.

Comment: Does the developer console complain about anything?

Comment: Is that the complete code? (Because I see some unclosed brackets and missing semicolons)

Comment: I think some errors in your code only. You are missing some brackets and semicolons may be........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a semicolon before `d.each` and make sure to close your `.each(function() {` and `.click(function() {` with `});`:

```
var diagopt = {
    autoOpen: true,
    title: 'Get a Quote Sent to you!',
    modal: true,
    width: 400,
    height: 350 }; // <== semicolon
d.each(function(){ //d is a variable holding jquery object
    $(this).click(function(eve){ // <== Note that eve is never used. 
        if($(this).attr('id') == links[1]) //array with id of target elements
        {
            $('#getquote').dialog(diagopt);
            return false;
        }
    }); // <== close the .click()
}); // <== close the .each()
```